# Is this map proper?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, inverse-function

I have a map $f:\mathbb{R}^{4n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4n-4}: (x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1-x_2,\dots,x_{n-1} - x_n)$ and I need to know if it is a proper map. It has been ages since I had topology and I wouldn't even know how to begin.

Note that every $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Consider the preimage of a point.

Comment: No they are not off, but I should have explained that every $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^4$. I will add this.

Comment: @arkeet, then I have a set of points that map to that point..

Comment: OK, now what is the definition of "proper"?

Comment: @arkeet, A map is proper if the pre-image of a compact set is compact. So I'd have to check whether this pre-image is compact, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe it's worth refreshing yourself on some topology/real analysis. But the relevant fact here is that a compact subsets of a metric space are bounded. (Also recall the Heine-Borel theorem: a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it's closed and bounded.)

Comment: yeah, I think I have an argument as to why it is not proper. The pre-image of for example the singleton $\{0\}$ is the set of all vectors whose components are equal. This is an unbounded set, hence non compact. Therefore the map is not proper. Thanks for the hint. :)